# How do I test for activity inactivity time

Tags: android, timeout, locking, android-widget

I'm wondering what is the highest level I can go in-order to know when the user interacts with my application

preface: I'd like to logout of my application after X seconds of user inactivity.
so what I did is create a service with a timer, and a toggle function which resets the timer to X time.
after X time has passed, an intent is raised, and a broadcast receiver catches that intent and preforms the logout (closing the open logged in activities as well...)

as for the actual question, I need to call the "Timer Toggle" function each time the user interacts with the application.
where is the highest place in the android app that I can know when the user interacts with the phone

The only thing I found is to implement onClick and onKeyPress for each activity, is there another better way? maybe in the Application class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's any other way aside from sending events from the `Activity` itself.
You could look at overriding [`Activity.onUserInteraction()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onUserInteraction%28%29).

But is it likely that the user will be in a single `Activity` of your application for "X seconds" without ever switching screens, or letting the device go into sleep?

I imagine it would be sufficient to update the timer/flag in `onCreate`, `onPause` and `onResume`.  Plus maybe some commonly-called functions within the `Activity`.

Comment: Well, it might happen because its a content app, so for example, the user might be reading something. but Ill think about maybe doing it your way.

Comment: but Ill think about maybe doing it your way.